# Imagenes no se cargan al compilar proyeto angular

Tags: angular

Mi actual ruta base:

```html
<base href="https://paginaweb/carpetaProyecto/">
```

Cargan los archivos CSS y JavaScript:

```
https://paginaweb/carpetaProyecto/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Pero las imágenes no. Retornan esta ruta:

```
https://paginaweb/assets/images/logo-sinproc.png
```

Está en la forma en que compilo

```sh
ng build --prod --base-href https://paginaWeb/uct/
```

¿Cómo lo podría solucionar?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes poner `<base href="./">` en el `<head>` para que todas las referencias sean relativas luego llamar a `ng build --prod` en la terminal.
tambien debes configurar en el htaccess del servidor la redireccion a index asi:

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^ index.html
</IfModule>
```

esto para para que sirvan los rotes de angular

Comment: Gracias si funciono solo que debi modificar mi base por `<base href="../../">`

Comment: a ok ya entendí `assets/` esta por fuera de `carpetaProyecto/`

Comment: @andrescastellanos por que tienes la carpeta `assets` por fuera de tu proyecto?. Generalmente se agrega con el `ng build --prod` a la misma carpeta de tu proyecto `dist/carpetaProyecto`

Comment: Esta dentro de mi proyecto esta es la ruta del assets/ `\uct\src\assets\images`. y cuando generlo el `ng build --prod` guardas mis css y js, la verdad no se que paso con las imagenes.